# Semantics: Why do we say that a "norm" is induced or derived form inner product when the two are equal?

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

What do people mean when they say that a norm is induced from an inner product? Why is it not the other way around?

Comment: not all norms come from an inner product http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity

Comment: When you have two objects and you can recover one from another and vice versa, then whether one induces the other or the other way around is really a matter of perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm is a function of one variable, the inner product is a function of two variables.  Given an inner product, one may define a norm from it as shown.  (We say the norm is induced by the inner product.) But not all norms are obtained in this way.

But, presumably in that mystery book you quote, they have started with some special type of norm, and constructed an inner product from it.  Then (according to Theorem 2) we get the norm back again using the formula, not some new norm, as you might expect.